# How to manipulate UITableView to edit cells according to header?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm almost finished with my little home project. But some main features I am not sure how to implement.

I have a UITableViewController that has 2 prototype custom cells. One as a sticky header and one as the content to be dequeued across the whole tableview. **I need the 
"ContentCell's" labels to change and repopulate according to input from the header.**

Here is a picture of the View Controller:

[image: Top: HeaderCell, Bottom: ContentCell]

I want the text field in the header to change the numberOfRowsInSection, and the labels of the cell. What is the best way to execute this?

Here is what I have already:

ReaderViewController.Swift:

```
import UIKit

class ReaderViewController: UITableViewController {


    let maxRows = 30
    var headerView: UIView?
    var book: Book?
    var stepperValue: Int?
    var rowCount = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let book = book{
            print(book.book)
        } else {
            print("no book")
        }
        tableView.rowHeight = 100

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 150.0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as? HeaderCell
        view?.backgroundColor = .cyan
        view?.stepper.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        headerView = view
        return view
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let num = stepperValue{
            if let count = book?.chapters[num].verses.count{
                rowCount = count
            } else {
                rowCount = 2
            }
        }
        print(rowCount)
        return rowCount
    }

    @IBAction func textFieldValueChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if let text = sender.text{
            if text.isEmpty{
                stepperValue = 1
            } else {
                stepperValue = Int(text)
                print(stepperValue)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    @IBAction func finishedEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {
        if let text = sender.text{
            stepperValue = Int(text)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
            "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell

        if let komik = cell.lbl{
            if let num = stepperValue {
                komik.text = book?.get(chapter: num, verse: indexPath.row)
            } else {
                //print("no text")
            }

        }
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
}
```

HeaderCell.Swift:

```
import UIKit

class ContentCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }



    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

ContentCell.swift:

```
import UIKit

class HeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var chapterTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func changeChapters(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        if chapterTextField.text!.isEmpty{
            sender.value = sender.stepValue
            chapterTextField.text = "\(sender.value)"
        } else {
            chapterTextField.text = "\(Int(sender.value))"
        }


    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

The app builds but the text field doesn't populate the ContentCells.

Comment: Your overall approach is correct but I dont think your textfieldValueChanged gets called as the textfield is in the header cell. This will get called only if its in the header cell and then you need to use delegates to pass the call to the controller. Let me know if you need more clarity on this.

Comment: Yes I do need a little more clarity. Could you give an example?

Comment: Sure, I ll add my answer.

Comment: can you accept as answer if it has worked for you.

Comment: It builds but the text field still doesn't populate the ContentCells.

Comment: does the delegate method get called?

Comment: No. I have opted to just use a label to represent to chapter of the verses being shown, but now the cell content won't change with the stepper value changing.

Answer (score 1):

Following up from my comment to the question. Here is my answer.

1. **Remove** and **disconnect** from interface builder 
   @IBAction func textFieldValueChanged(_ sender: UITextField 
   @IBAction func finishedEditing(_ sender: UITextField) from ReaderViewController.
2. I am using delegation, but you can also use blocks to communicate back to the controller.
3. finishedEditing method is not required since you update your stepper with every change in your textField.
4. Connect and place the valueChangeMethod in 1 inside the `headerCell` and from inside this method, call the delegate method.

Below is how your classes will look after making the above changes. 
**Perform steps 1 and 3 in ReaderViewController**

```
    //ReaderViewController

    import UIKit

    class ReaderViewController: UITableViewController, HeaderCellDelegate {


    let maxRows = 30
    var headerView: UIView?
    var book: Book?
    var stepperValue: Int?
    var rowCount = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let book = book{
            print(book.book)
        } else {
            print("no book")
        }
        tableView.rowHeight = 100

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    //HeaderCellDelegate
    func headerCellTextFieldChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let text = textField.text{
            if text.isEmpty{
                stepperValue = 1
            } else {
                stepperValue = Int(text)
                print(stepperValue)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 150.0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as? HeaderCell
        view?.textFieldDelegate = self
        view?.backgroundColor = .cyan
        view?.stepper.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        headerView = view
        return view
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let num = stepperValue{
            if let count = book?.chapters[num].verses.count{
                rowCount = count
            } else {
                rowCount = 2
            }
        }
        print(rowCount)
        return rowCount
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
            "ContentCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentCell

        if let komik = cell.lbl{
            if let num = stepperValue {
                komik.text = book?.get(chapter: num, verse: indexPath.row)
            } else {
                //print("no text")
            }

        }
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
}
```

**Perform steps 2 and 4 in HeaderCell file**

```
//HeaderCell

protocol HeaderCellDelegate
{
    func headerCellTextFieldChanged(_ textField: UITextField)
}

import UIKit

class HeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    weak var textFieldDelegate: HeaderCellDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var chapterTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func changeChapters(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        if chapterTextField.text!.isEmpty{
            sender.value = sender.stepValue
            chapterTextField.text = "\(sender.value)"
        } else {
            chapterTextField.text = "\(Int(sender.value))"
        }
    }


    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

       @IBAction func textFieldValueChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        textFieldDelegate?.headerCellTextFieldChanged(sender)
       }
    }
```

**Content Cell doesn't need change.**

This should definitely work. 
Let me know if it doesn't and what method does not get called by putting breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Add `textFieldValueChanged` and `finishedEditing` inside your `HeaderCell` and connect them, add two variables that will represent callbacks:

```
class HeaderCell: UITableViewCell {
    var textFieldValueChanged: ((UITextField) -> ())?
    var finishedEditing: ((UITextField) -> ())?

    @IBAction func textFieldValueChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        textFieldValueChanged?(sender)
    }

    @IBAction func finishedEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {
        finishedEditing?(sender)
    }

    // { Rest of your code }

}
```

In your `ReaderViewController` inside `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)` do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as? HeaderCell
        view?.backgroundColor = .cyan
        view?.stepper.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        headerView = view

        view?.textFieldValueChanged = { textField in
            if let text = sender.text{
                if text.isEmpty{
                    stepperValue = 1
                } else {
                    stepperValue = Int(text)
                    print(stepperValue)
                }
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        view?.finishedEditing = { textField in
            if let text = sender.text{
                stepperValue = Int(text)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        return view
}
```

Remove and disconnect from interface builder `@IBAction func textFieldValueChanged(_ sender: UITextField)` and `@IBAction func finishedEditing(_ sender: UITextField)` from your `ReaderViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add two things inside of your code.
firstly, you need to add extension for *UITextFieldDelegate* and add a delegate function.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //delegate method
//whenever you change anything inside of your text field this function will be called.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as? HeaderCell
        view?.backgroundColor = .cyan
        view?.stepper.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        view?.chapterTextField.delegate = self
        headerView = view

        return view
    }
```